# Does a combination of K integers exist, so that their sum is equal to a given number?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, backtracking, subset-sum

I've been breaking a sweat over this question I've been asked to answer (it's technically homework).
I've considered a hashtable but I'm kind of stuck on the exact specifics of how I'd make this work

Here's the question:

> Given *k* sets of integers *A*<sub>1</sub>,*A*<sub>2</sub>,..,*A*<sub>*k*</sub> of total size O(*n*), you should determine whether exist
>   *a*<sub>1</sub> ϵ *A*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub> ϵ *A*<sub>2</sub>,..,*a*<sub>*k*</sub> ϵ *A*<sub>*k*</sub>, such that *a*<sub>1</sub>+*a*<sub>2</sub>+..+*a*<sub>*k*−1</sub> =*a*<sub>*k*</sub>. Your algorithm should run in T<sub>*k*</sub>(*n*)
>   time, where T<sub>*k*</sub>(*n*) = O(*n*<sup>*k*/2</sup> × log *n*) for even *k*, and O(*n*<sup>(*k*+1)/2</sup>) for odd values of *k*.

Can anyone give me a general direction so that I can come closer to solving this?

Comment: congratulations on admitting homework. Do you have *any* answer to the problem (disregarding complexity)? If so, what do you analyze it's complexity as? Do you think your approach is completely wrong-headed, or are there specific parts that you think are faulty?

Comment: The only thing I could figure out that would work 100% was the most naive implementation of n^n (ie. checking ALL the options). Obviously this is not the right way to go :(

Comment: I wonder if this would be better suited to Math Overflow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Divide the k sets into two groups. For even k, both groups have k/2 sets each. For odd k, one group has (k+1)/2 and the other has (k-1)/2 sets. Compute all possible sums (taking one element from each set) within each group. For even k, you will get two arrays, each with n<sup>k/2</sup> elements. For odd k, one array has n<sup>(k+1)/2</sup> and the other array has n<sup>(k-1)/2</sup> elements. The problem is reduced to the standard one "Given two arrays, check if a specified sum can be reached by taking one element from each array".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems right intuitively, but I can't completely figure out how this actually reduced the problem. Can you elaborate a tiny bit?

Comment: Given two arrays of size O(n) each, you can find if a sum exists in O(n*log n). The solution is not too difficult. I would feel guilty if I give it out to you since you have mentioned it is a homework!

Comment: @viswanathgs: you can even solve the two arrays problem in O(n) time on average.

Comment: @unforgiven: That is only if the arrays are sorted, right? Or is there something I'm not looking at?